# How can I solve 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray' threw an exception?

Tags: matlab, asp.net-mvc-4

I got the following error with matlab in asp.net.

I installed "MATLAB Runtime" and followed the instruction by "Build a .NET Application" via

> https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-dotnet-application-with-matlab-code.html

And when I run via "IIS Express(Chrome)" in VS2019, I got the following error.
[image]

and in Output display.

> Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in MWArray.dll
>
> An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in MWArray.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray' threw an exception.

When I check the "Environment variable"

[image]

and when I check the path, I found "mclmcrrt9_6.dll"

[image]

sys info.

> VS2019
>
> debug platform : x64
>
> framework : 4.5.2

runtime of Web.config

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="MWArray" publicKeyToken="E1D84A0DA19DB86F" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.19.0.0" newVersion="2.19.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.6.0" newVersion="5.2.6.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.6.0" newVersion="5.2.6.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.